# Restarting a Youtube Player View (Invalidation does not work)

Tags: android, view, youtube, invalidation, android-youtube-api

Im having some problems with the Youtube Player View. I have a listview where the user selects the video to be reproduced among a few.

It only works well the first time a video is clicked in the list view. The second time the Youtube Player View does not change at all. I´ve tried invalidating the Youtube Player View with invalidate and then calling again initalize but it does not work. This is the relevant code (the setOnItemClickListener of the listView):

```
videosListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> pariente, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Video chosen = (Video) pariente.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String url = chosen.getUrl();
            IDVideo = getYoutubeVideoId(url);

            youtubeView.initialize(keyDeveloper,
                    new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
                                YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0,
                                YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                            if (!wasRestored) {
                                player.cueVideo(IDVideo);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be re-initializing the playerview, just re-cueing.  I actually did a tutoral that doesn't have a list view but three videos which can be switched out by clicking buttons.  [You can check out the video and source code here](http://androiddev101.com/episode-12-youtube-it-all-night-long/).

Also there is some code for using youtube thumbnails as well if you would want them for your lists.